# nohup can not get output

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

OS: ubuntu 20.0
I write a simple python with print

```
import time
a = 0
while 1:
    a +=1
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and I run command

```
nohup python3 test2.py > 3.log 2>&1 &
```

then  next

```
cat 3.log
```

only got

*nohup: ignoring input*

if I remove last & run

```
nohup python3 test2.py > 3.log 2>&1
```

get 3.log output

```
1
2
3
4
```

but nohup will be kill after terminor close .how can I get output with &

```
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$ nohup python3 test2.py > 3.log 2>&1
^C
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$ cat 3.log
nohup: ignoring input
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$ ^C
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$ nohup python3 test2.py > 3.log 2>&1 &
[3] 83030
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$ cat 3.log
nohup: ignoring input
django@django-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01:~/swap_hb$
```

Comment: Why are you using `nohup`? Bash has a built-in `disown -h` that does the actual "no HUP" part, and the only other things it does is redirecting stdin from `/dev/null` and stdout and stderr to `nohup.out` if they aren't already going to a file.

Comment: That said, redirect `</dev/null` explictly and you'll avoid the message you ask about here.

Comment: ...btw, for the future, [unix.se] is more appropriate for questions about using command-line tools; this is the right place for questions that are specific to developing software (in the context of shells, writing scripts).

Comment: You could add `-u` to unbuffer `sys.stdout` like: `nohup python3 -u  test2.py > 3.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: nohup python3 -u  test2.py > 3.log 2>&1 is work thanks